# "wodim: Permission denied. Cannot open SCSI driver!" how to solve?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, cd, cd-image

When I'm executing a cd writing command `cdrecord -v -eject speed=48 dev=/dev/sg1 /tmp/newcd.iso` it will output some errors in my log file like,

```
wodim: Permission denied. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
```

Any one know how to solve this issue? 
Please help to find a solution

Comment: when your denied access to a resource (esp system resource), it either means your not the owner(root) or it's potentially dangerous to use it. try the **sudo** prefix on such resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you are not root. The root account is essential to access system resources. Use

```
sudo cdrecord -v -eject speed=48 dev=/dev/sg1 /tmp/newcd.iso
```

to become root. You will be prompted for administrator password and then the process will start.

Comment: Any ideas if even using `sudo` results in the same error message?

Comment: Are you in the sudoers file?

Comment: Of course. I'm not running the exact command as in the question, but just plain `cdrecord -scanbus`. Funny that recording CDs actually works, but not `-scanbus`.

Comment: BTW, this answer is not completely right. The root account **is not** essential to record a CD. All it takes is for the user to be in the `cdrom` group.

Comment: @devius thanks, I will investigate this case further. Neither `wodim` nor `cdrecord` work with `-scanbus` switch for me too.

Comment: With Ubuntu 18.04 I suddenly have the same issue: "Cannot open SCSI driver!"; This is new, I burnt hundreds of CD and DVD from CLI.  I am member of cdrom group all the time, does not help. Using sudo cdrecord .... DOES HELP. But it is weird and stupid to use root rights for CD burning!  QUESTION: What is the cause, where is a fix described??